# change value of a javascript function when click on button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to play sound A when click button A, sound B when click B etc, in HTML5 audio, using javascript.  I am working though the code and I am getting confused with my functions and vars.  But I think the best way would be to have a function where playAudio(a) plays a.mp3 etc but I cant get it working.

The example below has the input ID defining the sound being played, but I cant make it dynamic.

Javascript

```
var a = sounds/a.mp3
var b = sounds/b.mp3

function playX() {
    var xAudio = document.getElementById('xxx');
         xAudio.src = $("#audiofile").val();          
    xAudio.play();   
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="audiofile" type="text" value="sounds/a.mp3" /><br />
<input id="audiofileb" type="text" value="sounds/b.mp3" /><br />

<button id="play" onclick="playX();">        A    </button>
<button id="play" onclick="playX();">        B    </button>
<button id="play" onclick="playX();">        C   </button>



<audio id="xxx">  
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = sounds/a.mp3
var b = sounds/b.mp3

function playX(id) {
    var xAudio = document.getElementById('xxx');
         xAudio.src = $("#audiofile"+id).val();          
    xAudio.play();   
}
```

and html:

```
<input id="audiofileA" type="text" value="sounds/a.mp3" /><br />
<input id="audiofileB" type="text" value="sounds/b.mp3" /><br />
<input id="audiofileC" type="text" value="sounds/c.mp3" /><br />

<button id="play" onclick="playX('A');">        A    </button>
<button id="play" onclick="playX('B');">        B    </button>
<button id="play" onclick="playX('C');">        C   </button>
```

Comment: yes - thanks.  I was looking before the last edit and it wasnt working and didnt make sense.  The edit works and I see how its working.  Thanks (need 5 mins for tick)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.

Pass the filename as a parameter:

```
<button id="play" onclick="playX('sounds/a.mp3');">A</button>


function playX(file) {
    xAudio.src = file         
    xAudio.play();   
}
```

Comment: i think the code was using the audio tag to bring the html5 audio into play.  This code doesnt work for me - maybe that is why?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery you can do something like this:

```
<button id="play" data-audiotrack="audiofile">        A    </button>
<button id="play" data-audiotrack="audiofileb">        B    </button>
<button id="play" data-audiotrack="audiofilec">        C   </button>

$('#play').click(function() {
    var audioTrack = $(this).data('audiotrack');
    var xAudio = document.getElementById(audioTrack);
    xAudio.src = $("#audiofile").val();          
    xAudio.play();
});
```

Comment: id prefer not to use jq for size, but there may be some benefits in this code so I may use it. Ill try it out thanks